# HTML5 Canvas showing issue When it is in a div container

Tags: html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

Here is My Demo http://jsfiddle.net/9D4L4/2/

I am using `canvas` element for the Image.

The `DIV` which contain `canvas` Element not taking the `Line-height.`
I want to make the canvas element verticaly center to the div. Please Help me

**HTML**

```
<h1>Normal Image </h1>
<div>
    <img src="http://jeevanmukti.info/images/key.gif" />

</div>
<br><br><br>

    <h1>When i use canvas </h1>

<div>
    <canvas >1111</canvas> 

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div{background:grey; width:100px; height:100px; text-align:center; line-height:100px; }
img{max-width:100%; max-height:100%}
canvas{background:url('http://jeevanmukti.info/images/key.gif') no-repeat center center; padding:0; margin:0; max-width:100%; max-height:100%}
```

**I want the Whole Canvas(in red color) to be the vertically center of that DIV**

Comment: @Mr. Alien......U der???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add

```
canvas{vertical-align: middle;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update below css attribute in your code :

```
     div{margin:0 auto;}
```

Answer (score -1):

Giving the canvas a height of 100px will do it, so the canvas will fill the height of the parent DIV